# How do I generate infinite random numbers of pair of dice until they are equal?

Tags: c++, loops, random-seed

I'm trying to simulate a program that will roll a pair of dice and it will generate the results until the variables are equal, however I can't figure this out.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() { 
    const int MIN_VALUE = 1;
    const int MAX_VALUE = 6;

    int die1,die2;

    unsigned seed = time(0);
    srand(seed);

    die1 = (rand()%(MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE +1)) + MIN_VALUE;
    die2 = (rand()%(MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE +1)) + MIN_VALUE;

    while(die1 == die2); {
        die1 = (rand()%(MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE +1)) + MIN_VALUE;
        die2 = (rand()%(MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE +1)) + MIN_VALUE;

        cout<<"Value of die 1  is"<<die1<<endl;
        cout<<"Value of die 2 is" <<die2<<endl;
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please always explain the problem thoroughly. “I can’t figure this out” doesn’t give any information what’s wrong. Are there compilation errors? Wrong results? What are the results? And first step is to run the code with a debugger line by line to see what it is doing and include the things you found out by doing that.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the feedback. I will explain my questions specifically next time.

Comment: @ChaLaHeadChaLa Please, not next time. Edit the question and explain your question now. It's not clear what are you asking about and what is your problem.

Comment: C++11 `<random>` facilities add easier distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two mistakes in `while(die1 == die2);`.

The `==` makes the loop continue while the values are equal, but you want the opposite.
The condition could be endless if the two dice start off equal (because the rerolling never happens, see below).
Otherwise it will be "never".
The semicolon will prevent the `while` from having any effect on the following `{}`, it will be executed exactly once, in case the loop is not endless, otherwise never.

So change to:

```
while(die1 != die2)
{
    /* reroll */
}
```

In case you want to make your code easier to maintain and read, investigate about `do {} while();`.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of issues here:

- The `;` at the end of line where the `while` statement begins means that the `while` is not connected to the block of code below. Remove it. (if `die1` value equals `die2` at the beginning itself, you will have an infinite loop there itself.)
- The condition to check is `die1 != die2` because you want to roll the dice as long as they are not equal.

See **[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AiVPVjBuniRyR0lO)**.